# Getting For Without Next Error, not sure why

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop throw rows and say "if the cell in this column begins with 49, hide the entire row". Here's my code:

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Rows("AK" & i).Value Like "49*" Then
        Rows("AK" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next i
```

It keeps stopping on the last line and saying "For without next". Can it not see the FOR line three lines up? This is just one of many statements I have like this but I think fixing this one will help me format the others. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your missing an `End If` (The wording is like that because It sees a `Next` within an `If` block without a matching `For`; which is illegal)

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Range("AK" & i).Value Like "49*" Then
        Range("AK" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: I added the `end if` to the code, now it's giving me an `application-defined or object-defined error` on 2nd line.

Comment: You need to replace `Rows("AK" & i)` with `Range("AK" & i)`

Comment: I missed that the first go at it. Your solution worked, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

End if is missing !
It is required if you put the next instruction on another line.