# Looping though only selected sheets to proceed several steps

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file which contains several sheets where I have to cut-copy from one column to another.

When I use the code on one specific sheet it works perfectly, yet while I've already tried to use e.g. Sheets(Array("ThisSheet", "ThatSheet")).Select and it worked partially, because after row 131 it pastes the cut data in the wrong direction, which is odd. Nonetheless, no idea how to solve it.

Could you please help me with the code? I'd trupy appreciate it. In the comments you can find names of the specific columns only, so please simply ingore it.

```
Sub TABFixLoop_Main()
' TABFix Macro Loop Core Scratch
' === Declaces which tabs are in the loop ========
' === Exceptions: ES20, IT40, IT43, IT44, IT45, PT20 ===

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Sheets As Range
Set Sheets = Sheets(Array("BE00", "CH10", "CZ00", "DK00", "ES00", "FI00", "IT00", "LU30", "NL00", "NO00", "PT00", "SE00"))
For Each ws In Sheets
  Do
    ' Fit the columns size
    ws.Activate
    ws.Columns.AutoFit

    ' Putting value ranges in correct places:

    ' MMDoc #
    Range("P5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("N5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    ws.Columns("N:N").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    Range("P5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents

    ' Age
    Range("Q5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("O5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("Q5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents

    ' PO Vendor
    Range("R5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("P5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("P5").NumberFormat = "0"
    Range("R5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents

    ' Business Area
    Range("S5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("R5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("S5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents

    ' Remove empty columns
    ws.Columns("S:T").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    ' Add formula to count aging ranges
    Range("U5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+IF(RC[-6]<=30,""0-30"",IF(RC[-6]<=60,""31-60"",IF(RC[-6]<=90,""61-90"",IF(RC[-6]<=120,""91-120"",IF(RC[-6]<=180,""121-180"",IF(RC[-6]<=365,""181-365"",IF(RC[-6]>365,"">365"","""")))))))"
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
  Loop Until ws = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Active
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code does not work even for 1 sheet, you are doing something very wrong. You should be getting an error `For without Next`, because you do not have next on your code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426295/getting-for-without-next-error-not-sure-why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "BE00", "CH10", "CZ00", "DK00", "ES00", "FI00", "IT00", "LU30", "NL00", "NO00", "PT00", "SE00"
            ws.Columns.AutoFit
            shiftdata ws, "P", "N"
            shiftdata ws, "Q", "O"
            shiftdata ws, "R", "P"
            With ws.Range("U5")
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=+IF(RC[-6]<=30,""0-30"",IF(RC[-6]<=60,""31-60"",IF(RC[-6]<=90,""61-90"",IF(RC[-6]<=120,""91-120"",IF(RC[-6]<=180,""121-180"",IF(RC[-6]<=365,""181-365"",IF(RC[-6]>365,"">365"","""")))))))"
                .Copy Destination := ws.Range(.Address & ":" & .End(xlDown).Address)
            End With
        Case Else


    End Select
Next ws
End Sub

Sub shiftdata(ws As Worksheet, strFrom As String, StrTo As String)
Dim r As Range

    Set r = ws.Range(strFrom & "5:" & strFrom & ws.Range(strFrom & "5").End(xlDown).Row)
    r.Copy
    ws.Range(StrTo & "5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    r.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still a VBA beginner and this will definitely help me to spend less time and use the code more wisely. I really appreciate it.